# What we sold yesterday was/were a cat and oxen

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Which is correct in my sentence? No-one really seems to have ever posted such a sophisticated question.

1. What we sold yesterday *was/were* a cat and three oxen.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/singular-or-plural-verb-after-what) is nearly as sophisticated, and there are others if you search (unfortunately searching for "what" is hard). It seems to be a matter of style/choice.

Comment: @Stuart I've added a << what-cleft >> tag, which will make searching easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb Agreement in English Wh-Clefts: 'What differentiates A from B is/are ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405879/verb-agreement-in-english-wh-clefts-what-differentiates-a-from-b-is-are) '[Based on "Corpus-Based Study_ "Seung-Ah Lee],  I'd say that

2) What differentiates apples from oranges is their colors and sizes.

and

5') What differentiate apples from oranges are their colors and sizes.

(both with internal agreement)

are both acceptable. 'What' = 'the set of things that' in (2) and = ''things that' in (5').'

Answer (score 1):

The grammar here just isn't in everyday English usage and is overly convoluted.

The proper way of expressing

> What we sold yesterday was/were a cat and three oxen.

is

> We sold a cat and three oxen yesterday

or

> Yesterday, we sold a cat and three oxen

"*what/was/were*" just isn't really needed here to make the sentence clearly understood.

Comment: I just made this example up in order to understand which pronoun to use in such a case.

Comment: And this is why the sentence is re-arranged to prevent the was/were conflict.  I get that you're trying to work out how to refer to a single/multiple combination, but I can't think of an example sentence that would use this where rewording wouldn't make the meaning clearer and easier to read.

Comment: I'll have to start downvoting if you give more 'forget your perceived question; rewrite in this improved way' answers. Perhaps OP's example could be improved, but they are asking about verb agreement in a wh-cleft with a plural-form patient referent (eg 'a cat and three oxen'). // 'Yesterday, we sold a cat and three oxen' should be seen as, in many contexts, a better way to phrase this by most Anglophones. ELU is intended for more academic questions.

Answer (score -3):

I think none of them is correct. It should be "What we sold yesterday are a cat and three oxen."
You don't need to use "was/were" to indicate truth. The present tense is enough. Since a cat and three oxen are two different things, you need to use "are".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I have managed to understand, both *was* and *were* are correct, aren't they?